# Why is this .net regex failing in freespace mode?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use a regex I made in freespace mode, so I can add comments and keep it maintainable for the future. The program below is a sample of the problem, but the actual regex where I ran into this problem is much more complex.

```
        private static readonly string regexTest1 = @"(?((?=A))(A)|(\w))";
        private static readonly string regexTest2 = @"(?x)
        (?        # If ...
        ((?=A))   # next character is A
        (A)|      # Capture in group 1, else ...
        (\w))     # Capture in group 2 (and EndIf).
        ";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Match m1 = new Regex(regexTest1).Match("A");
            Match m2 = new Regex(regexTest2).Match("A");  // Exception!
        }
```

trying to use regexTest2, the program breaks with a "token not recognized" exception. It seems to be the conditional '(?' and the end parenthesis three lines further that's causing the problem, but why can't they be split up over several lines?

As a work around I'm using a concatenated string like this ...

```
private static readonly string regexTest2 =
@"(?"          // If ...
+@"((?=A))"    // next character is A
+@"(A)|"       // Capture in group 1, else ...
+@"(\w))";     // Capture in group 2 (and EndIf).
```

But I find the @'s and "" distract too much from the regex parts.
What are the restrictions in .NET for breaking up a regex this way? Is there another (clearer) way I'm overlooking?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "freespace mode"? Do you actually mean "a multi-line verbatim string literal"? (Using non-standard terminology without explaining it causes confusion...)

Comment: Your `regexTest2` contains literal whitespace and "comments" in it. That's why it's breaking.

Comment: Regexes are never really readable, and moving the strings around will generally create these problems. Keep them inline and you're good to go. That's also the reason your workaround works, btw

Comment: Dumb observation but: `regexTest2` is NOT the same as `regexTest1` and you did not specify `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` (which also enables comments). If you fix that and you keep `(?(` together (otherwise it'll be seen as a group construct) then it _should_ work

Comment: @JonSkeet From a regex perspective, [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html) calls it 'free spacing'. But from a C# perspective, it is indeed a multi-line verbatim string literal.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti the regex starts with (?x), which should be the same as using the RegexOptions. However, keeping the (?( together does indeed the trick (although I can't quite work out why). 

Could you make this an answer, instead of a comment?, Then I can make it the accepted answer.

Comment: @user20943029: Note that that guide refers to the regular expression flavour itself supporting that "mode". So maybe there's something in `Regex` itself that would support it. It's worth differentiating between the C# feature that allows a string literal to contain line breaks, and anything that `Regex` will do with such a string. The "ignore whitespace option" does look like it should work, so I would suggest highlighting that you're using that within your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `(?` on its own line causes a problem for the parser. I don't know why, but it's *reasonably* easy to work round. I would personally use the explicit `RegexOptions` rather than the `(?x)`, but both work:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string pattern = @"
(?((?=A)) # If next character is A
(A)|      # Capture in group 1, else ...
(\w))     # Capture in group 2 (and EndIf).
";

Match match = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace).Match("A");
```

Or:

```cs
string pattern =
@"(?x)    # Ignore pattern whitespace
(?((?=A)) # If next character is A
(A)|      # Capture in group 1, else ...
(\w))     # Capture in group 2 (and EndIf).
";

Match match = new Regex(pattern).Match("A");
```

Note that while it would be more readable to write:

```cs
string pattern = @"
(?x) # Ignore pattern whitespace
...
";
```

... that won't work due to the whitespace (line break) before the option. It doesn't throw an exception (it's a valid regex) but it doesn't match as you want it to.

If you definitely want to separate the outermost grouping construct from the first one, you can give it a name:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string pattern = @"
(?'outer' # If...
((?=A))   # next character is A
(A)|      # Capture in group 1, else ...
(\w))     # Capture in group 2 (and EndIf).
";

Match match = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace).Match("A");
```